# Modify a function to check for a pair of sub-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a function which checks if a substring is present in a database job-name.The input to the function is a list of standard substrings and the list of database job names.

```
import re
substrings = {'archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b'}
joblist=['ora123.archivebackup.b','ora123.logbackup.b','ora123.fullbackup.b','ora123.dailybackup.b']

FIND_FILE = re.compile('|'.join(s for s in substrings))
matches = set()
for job in joblist:
    match = FIND_FILE.search(job)
    if match:
        print(match.group(0), "found")
        matches.add(match.group(0))
m=substrings - matches
print("Missing:", substrings - matches)
```

This function is working fine and I am getting the below o/p:

```
archivebackup.b found
logbackup.b found
fullbackup.b found
dailybackup.b found
Missing: set()
```

Now I want to modify this function such that it also takes a list of database names and checks for the combination of database name and substring in each job and if any substring is missing give the o/p as the database name along with job name.

```
dbname=['ora123','ora456']
```

I tried the below approach, and it works partially fine with displaying the missing jobs.

```
FIND_FILE = re.compile('|'.join(s for s in substrings))
FIND_FILE1 = re.compile('|'.join(d for d in dbname))
matches = set()
for db in dbname:
    for job in joblist:
        match = FIND_FILE1.search(job)
        if match:
            print(match.group(0), "found")
            matches.add(match.group(0))
m=substrings - matches
print("Missing:", substrings - matches)
```

Comment: do you need to use re? because `('archivebackup.b' in 'ora123.archivebackup.b')`
can check substring

Comment: it needs to check the db name 'ora123' also using 're' .

Comment: db name also works by `if 'ora123'  in 'ora123.archivebackup.b'`

Comment: i need to use it as a function and also there will be too many 'if' conditions.
So if the same functions can be modified to accomodate the dbanme check it would be helpful.Also note that 'substrings' is a standard set of strings,but dbname keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

Substrings and matches both have the same value so using the '-' operator will yield an empty set.

Comment: yes...that is fine.The question is how to check for the dbname as well.